# PowerBi multiples values in the filter by concatenatex

Tags: powerbi

Someone can help me?

I need do filter in my dash basead in multiples values in the filter, if usuary selected two informations it need to apper, if selected one, one information, if no seletected, show everthing.

My code:

Max Value =

VAR SUC = CONCATENATEX (FILTER(TABLE[COLUMN]; CONCATENATE("""";CONCATENATE(TABLE[COLUMN]);""""));"; ")
VAR SOLUTION = CALCULATE(SUM(TABLE[COLUMN2]);
--ANOTHER FILTERS--
FILTER(ALL(TABLE); TABLE[COLUMN3] = VALUE;
--ERROR--
IF(ISFILTERED(TABLE[COLUMN]); TABLE[COLUMN] IN {SUC} --ONE VALUE OK, TWO VALUES SELETECTED= NULL--; TABLE[COLUMN] IN ALLSELETECTED(TABLE[COLUMN]) --ALL VALUES - OK--)
RETURN SOLUTION

---

-- TEXT -- IS A COMMENTARY

Comment: It is hard to tell what is your expected output based on the formula, try show the image with sample data and expected output

Comment: Add sample data to your post and show us your desired result